# Reply to message and wait for adaptive card action

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

The conversation page in the Teams Dev Docs lists a scenario that I am trying to implement:

> ### Updating messages
>
> Rather than have your messages be static snapshots of data, your bot can dynamically update messages inline after sending them. You can use dynamic message updates for scenarios such as poll updates, *modifying available actions after a button press*, or any other asynchronous state change.

In my code, I create a message and attach an Adaptive card.

```
var cardReply = activity.CreateReply();
cardReply.AddAdaptiveCard(card);
```

If I reply to the user using `PostAsync`, then I do not get the `ResponseResourceId` that I need to update the reply.

```
// PostAsync return Task, no ResourceResponse
await context.PostAsync(cardReply);

// OnDataItemInput is called when Action.Submit is triggered
context.Wait(this.OnDataItemInput);
```

If instead, I reply to the activity, then the continuation delegate (`context.Wait`) is not called. The continuation that is executed is the previous dialog on the stack.

```
// OnDataItemInput is never called 
context.Wait(this.OnDataItemInput);

ConnectorClient connector = 
    new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

var cardReplyResource = await connector
    .Conversations
    .ReplyToActivityAsync(cardReply);
```

How do I send an `AdaptiveCard` with input items and have the bot wait for the `Action.Submit` response?

Comment: I have a few questions. Is `AddAdaptiveCard()` an extension method you made yourself? Also, why are you calling `context.Wait()` at the beginning of that code instead of the end?

Comment: 1. Yes, but it is just a copy of the code from the v4 SDK. It is most certainly *not* the issue.
2. It doesn't matter where that call is made, since it is just a "marker " of sorts, telling the framework what delegate to invoke when it comes back.

Comment: So you're using V4 and not V3?

Comment: Correct.
Microsoft.Bot.Builder version="3.16.1.38846" 
Microsoft.Bot.Connector version="3.16.1.38846" 
Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams version="0.9.0"

Comment: That sounds like V3 and not V4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The activity message generated by the user pressing the Submit button, received by your bot, will have a `replyToId` field -- that's the ID of the message you want to update.

If you need a way to distinguish these activity messages from others, you can give the Action.Submit button an `id` or use its `data` field - the `value` object of the activity will tell you that.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Bill. And love the suit in your avatar picture. ;)

Comment: @bill-bliss-msft Is this property still available? At least using the emulator (v4), I don't see any `replyToId` field in postBack messages from an Adaptive Card.